# how to kill the kubernetes job if the command return code is nonzero

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

There is command in my Kubernetes Manifest File which when runs there would be return code 7 (sometimes). Though the return code is 7 ideally the Kube Job doesn't fail, but it would complete successfully if the return code is 0.

How do we setup the Job to fail if the Return code is non-zero?

Comment: Can you update question with your manifests please?

Comment: the command I am running in the manifest file is application specific which watch for the file. In case if the file is unavailable the command exit with a message saying timedout if the file is found then it exits with a successful message.

On failure we  can see the echo $? as Non-Zero if it is successful then echo $? is 0. The problem for us is the Kubernetes job doesn't end even though the return code is non-zero

Comment: @Ram as suggested above, could you please provide the manifest file that reproduces your problem. You don't have to include any app specific parts, just enough to reproduce the issue.